# Boolean used as condition of if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, boolean, addeventlistener

I'm attempting to change the background color of a page for every time you click on the button element, like so:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var isPurple = false;

button.addEventListener("click",function(){
if(isPurple){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  isPurple = false;
}else {
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
  isPurple = true;
 }
});
```

I'm having a difficult time understanding this code, namely how `isPurple`    works in this example. We're defining a variable assigned to Boolean false, which is used as a condition of the if statement, yet how does JavaScript know to reference the background color based solely on false? The condition of the if statement `if(isPurple)` is saying "if false" but *what* is false? When the page loads it's white but how does that get assigned a value of false?

Comment: It gets that value in the code you have written: `var isPurple = false;` (and after that, you toggle the variable on every click)

Comment: `isPurple` is the variable that is either `true` or `false`. It gets assigned those values directly within either the `if` or the `else` statement. This variable has nothing to do with any background color. It’s just a state that represents the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isPurple` is a variable, its value can change. It's testing whether the *current* value of the variable is `true` or `false`. Notice that after it performs the test, it changes the value with:

```
isPurple = false;
```

The test

```
if (isPurple)
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
if (isPurple == true)
```

The next time you click the button, that test will no longer succeed. As a result, each time you click the button, it alternates between `white` and `purple`.

Answer (score 0):

> how does JavaScript know to reference the background color based solely on false?

It does not know.

It is a logical assumption/relation in the code. The value of `true` and `'purple'` does only exist in the `if` clause, as well as the value of `false` and `'white'`.

Maybe it is easier to use the color itself, with an object for toggling the color.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var color = 'white';

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    color = { white: 'purple' , purple: 'white' }[color];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
});
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```